# Foreign key with OR logic

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, orm, ef-code-first

I have CodeFirst design like this:

```
public class Email
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    //many other props
}

public class Company
{
    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

In a good way, Email can belong to **only one** foreign key: CompanyId or UserId. But now it allows CompanyId and UserId. It's wrong. Anyway, that design with nullables is ugly. For example, to get all emails linked to companies I need do this:

```
var companyEmails = _context.Emails.Where(x => x.CompanyId.HasValue);
```

I feel there is a better approach to define multiply foreign keys with OR logic. Please, help me find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the only one reference to `Company` or `User`, that mean it will not be `FK` and also you should have additional field with description, to which table this field points.

Alternatively, you can try **Table per Hierarchy** approach. At this case database table will remain almost the same, only new `Discriminator` column will be implicitly added, to distinguish classes, but you will can to write more *"elegant"* code:

```
public abstract class Email
{
     public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyEmail : Email
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class UserEmail : BaseEmail
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var companyEmails = _context.Emails.OfType<CompanyEmail>();
//underlying query:
//select * from dbo.Emails where Discriminator = 'CompanyEmail'
```

Comment: Thank you! btw there is a [good tutorial for inheritance strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)